# ISO Standard Security Field

Tags: iso27000

What is the ISO standard that helps entities to implement security processes, concepts in the application security field ?

Comment: I Googled "security processes, concepts in the application security field" and got many links to ISO/IEC 27034. Please do some research before posting here else your answers will end up being links to well-known resources (like the answer you accepted).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the [ISO/IEC 27034-1:2011](https://www.iso.org/standard/44378.html). The target audience is:

> The following audiences will benefit from ISO/IEC 27034 while carrying out their designated organizational roles:
>
> a) managers;
> b) provisioning and operation teams;
> c) acquisition personnel;
> d) suppliers; and
> e) auditors

To understand what this norm is actually for, read the following quote:

> The purpose of ISO/IEC 27034 is to assist organizations in integrating security seamlessly throughout the life cycle of their applications by:
> a) **providing concepts, principles, frameworks, components and processes;
>
> b) providing process-oriented mechanisms for establishing security requirements, assessing security risks, assigning a Targeted Level of Trust and selecting corresponding security controls and verification measures**;
> c) providing guidelines for establishing acceptance criteria to organizations outsourcing the development or operation of applications, and for organizations purchasing from third-party applications;
> d) **providing process-oriented mechanisms for determining, generating and collecting the evidence needed to demonstrate that their applications can be used securely under a defined environment**;
> e) supporting the general concepts specified in ISO/IEC 27001 and assisting with the satisfactory implementation of information security based on a risk management approach; and
> f) **providing a framework that helps to implement the security controls specified in ISO/IEC 27002 and other standards**.
>
> ISO/IEC 27034:
> a) applies to the underlying software of an application and to contributing factors that impact its security, such as data, technology, application development life cycle processes, supporting processes and actors; and
> b) applies to all sizes and all types of organizations (e.g. commercial enterprises, government agencies, non-profit organizations) exposed to risks associated with applications.

But:

> ISO/IEC 27034does not:
>
> a) provide guidelines for physical and network security;
> b) provide controls or measurements; or
> c) provide secure coding specifications for any programming language.

All controls can be found in ISO/IEC 27002 and other standards. Read more towards that in ISO/IEC 27000 and 27001.

<sup>All quotes are taken from: ISO/IEC 27034-1:2011(en)
Information technology — Security techniques — Application security.</sup>

Comment: OWASP also has this great project regarding ISO/IEC 27034: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_ISO_IEC_27034_Application_Security_Controls_Project